# Potential false accusation and how to handle this

Tags: minor

I am a 22-year-old male, and last fall, I found this girl in an online chat site. When I asked her age, she told me she was 19. We exchanged numbers and started texting a lot every day. I had started liking her, and I told her about my feelings. She said she needed time, but in February, she finally said that she was ready to be in a relationship with me. It has been about two months now.

This morning, I received a text from her number saying that the person is her mother and she is a "minor", and she will be pressing charges against me. I am very scared. I have all the evidence of the texts she sent me, but I am petrified. How do I handle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sexting and age](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3446/sexting-and-age)

Comment: Talk to a lawyer.

Comment: 1) Which jurisdiction? 2) How old is the girl?

Comment: @erebus, her mother did not tell me. The girl said that she is 19. Her mother says that she is a minor. I am very confused.

Comment: I'm afraid that it's impossible to answer your question without further information. For instance, if the girl lives in Mississippi (where the age of majority is 21), she could in fact be 20 years old and still be a minor.

Comment: @erebus If the girl were 19 or 20 and from Mississippi then there would be no problem because the age difference between that and the OP's is not that great.

Comment: From what she told me, she is from Washington state.

Comment: You handle this by stopping the relationship and moving on.  Take it as a life lesson that no one is what they seem online. While they might be a 12 year old girl, they might also be a 53 year old man.  Mom might want to "press charges" but will quickly learn that texting with someone you think is 19 isn't a crime.  "Mom" might also not exist.  Just move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by not continuing the relationship. It is not a crime to "have feelings for" a minor, or to express them, unless the court orders you to not do so. There is no law in Washington against sending lewd pictures *to* a minor, but being in possession of lewd pictures *of* a minor is a felony. Once a court has judged a thing to be ["erotic material"](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9.68&full=true), there are labeling-related restrictions on further distribution. It therefore depends on exactly what you did.

Comment: I never sent a single obscene picture of me. Neither did I ask her for any. There was one occasion of sexting, and that is all. For me, it was purely platonic.

Comment: Then you have even less to worry about.

Comment: Incidentally, the title suggests that there was a false accusation -- what part of this do you think was false?

Comment: I believe that her mother thinks I was manipulating her purely for sexual interests. The very first text she sent me read something like "...I have alerted authorities and will be pressing charges..." I am confused as to charges against what.

Comment: I think this answer makes sense. I tried to find something in the Washington Criminal Code that would be relevant here, but no success.

Comment: Sounds like mom is just making things up, quite possibly because she doesn't know better (assuming, of course, that it really is mom and that the correspondent really is a minor, something that might be possible to sleuth out).